# How do I make vertices equidistant from a given center?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm trying to model a pen holder that came with my graphic tablet. After editing and extruding a UV sphere, I end up with a flat bottom that's not perfectly circular (because of some proportional editing I did before extruding). I've highlighted where the errors are in red. How can I make all the vertices on this flat bottom equidistant from a given center (and therefore aligned in a circle)? Here's the Dropbox [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfk02reo1t701ub/pen%20holder%2C%201.blend?dl=0) to the file.

[image]

I've tried to scale all the vertices to 0 while in Bottom Ortho view, but I can't scale them back up to get the equidistant points I want. The only other alternative I can think of is to extrude a part of the mesh while it's still circular.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Select the ring of vertices
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Then hit <kbd>1</kbd>.

   Or *Mesh > Transform > To Sphere*