# Conform selected edges or vertices to the objects surface

Tags: constraints

[image]

Hi all,

I would like to scale the selected vertices inwards and make them to stick on to the surface of the cylinder that i have placed in the centre. the cylinder is not joined to the plane.Would be awsome if some one would help.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the object you want edge loop to stick to is circular (cylinder) then the edge loop should become circular. This can be easily done either via default command <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then setting the factor to 1 or via LoopTools addon, *Circle* option. See also [How do I make vertices equidistant from a given center?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35228/how-do-i-make-vertices-equidistant-from-a-given-center)

Note to avoid making faces too distorted, in this case outer edge loop shown on screenshot is better to be moved towards cylinder a bit or add one more edge loop in between existing ones.

[image]